# Calling post_exists() causes white screen in after_setup_theme

Tags: theme-development

My theme is executing code in response to the `after_setup_theme` action. My code uses the function `post_exists` and when I use this function I am getting the 'white screen of death'. I have debugging on and logging, but when this error occurs no error is being written to the log.

Any idea what the heck could be going wrong?

```
if ( !defined('MY_THEME_HEADER_POST') )
    define('MY_THEME_HEADER_POST', 'MY_THEME_header_post');
if ( !defined('MY_THEME_HEADER_POST_CONTENT') )
    define('MY_THEME_HEADER_POST_CONTENT', '<nav>...</nav>');

if ( ! function_exists( 'MY_THEME_setup' ) ) :

    function MY_THEME_setup() {
        load_theme_textdomain( 'MY_THEME', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

        ... other theme setup

        // Problem occurs if I include the below code
        if (post_exists( MY_THEME_HEADER_POST ) == 0) {
            wp_insert_post(array(
               'post_title'    => MY_THEME_HEADER_POST,
               'post_content'  => MY_THEME_HEADER_POST_CONTENT,
               'post_status'   => 'publish'));
        }
    }
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'MY_THEME_setup' );
```

Comment: What are the errors in your error log? That should give you a clue.

Comment: You need to include the core file that define `post_exists()`